# How to print the contents of a two-dimensional array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, printing, char

I'm trying to print an array of characters in C but i can't print everything.
I want to print :
b1
b2
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char def[3][10];     //define a multidimensional array of characters 
  strcpy(def[0],"b1"); //insert "b1" at first line
  strcpy(def[1],"b2"); //insert "b2" at first line
  printf("%s",def);    //print everything?
}
```

The above code prints just `b1`. I already tried :

```
printf("%s",def[0]);
printf("%s",def[1]);
```

But i have error "invalid use of array with unspecified bounds"

Comment: You can't just print a multidimensional array of characters. What do you want it to print?

Comment: i tried to print each line separately but i couldn't.

Comment: @Dchris: Then, why don't you post the code you tried?

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: I edited post.I included what i tried and what i want print

Comment: @Dchris Show your real code and your real error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%s", def);
```

`%s` conversion specification expects a string. `def` is an array of strings and not a string.

To print the first string do this:

```
printf("%s", def[0]);
```

if you want to print the second string then do this:

```
printf("%s", def[1]);
```

and if you want to print both strings:

```
printf("%s%s", def[0], def[1]);
```

To print all strings in your array:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof def / sizeof *def; i++)
{
    printf("%s", def[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first initialize array with syntax like so whole array gets null value.
and then do the same procedure you are able to get your strings at output.

syntax:
char def[3][10]={};

or
first define this array and then by bzero function make whole array to zero value.

bzero(def,sizeof(def));

you need to include stdlib.h header file in your program.

Comment: Empty initializer and `bzero` are not standard C, and these don't solve the problem because `strcpy` adds a termination null character at the end of the destination string, stopping `*printf`. Anyway, it's not so efficient to fill an array of something if it's not really needed. You just need a single `'\0'` to stop.

Answer (score 0):

You could print a whole multi-dimensional array of `char` as a single string, with a single call:

```
printf("%s", (char*) multiDimensionalArray);
```

Because elements of a multi-dimensional array are contiguos. But, exactly as simple arrays, `printf` stops at the first termination character, so it's usually pointless because we almost always have a termination character at the end of each "row" just like you, or some uninitialized garbage.

```
char def[3][2];

memcpy(def[0], "b1", 2);
memcpy(def[1], "b2", 2);

def[2][0] = '\0';

printf("%s", (char*) def);  // print everything
```

But use arrays this way is painful, what you need is a loop over the array.

(you can simply use `*puts` to print strings)